# great_expectations : expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema does not take json schema as input

Tags: python, json, pandas, jsonschema, great-expectations

I am trying to invoke

`expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema`

as per

https://legacy.docs.greatexpectations.io/en/latest/autoapi/great_expectations/dataset/dataset/index.html#great_expectations.dataset.dataset.Dataset.expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema

```
jschema = {
        "type" : "object",
     "properties" : {
         "xyz" : {"type" : "string"}
     }
        }
df_ge.expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema(column='abc',json_schema=jschema,row_condition="a=='1' and b=='2' and c=='3'",condition_parser='pandas')
```

however i got this error

```
File "/some/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/great_expectations/dataset/pandas_dataset.py", line 1554, in matches_json_schema
    val_json = json.loads(val)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

so i tried

```
df_ge.expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema(column='abc',json_schema=json.loads(str(jschema)),row_condition="a=='1' and b=='2' and c=='3'",condition_parser='pandas')
```

but then i get

```
df_ge.expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema(column='pg',json_schema=json.loads(str(pgschema)),row_condition="a=='1' and b=='2' and c=='3'",condition_parser='pandas')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

how can i create a proper json object to feed to this method?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a serialization format, so the only thing that can be JSON is a string of bytes. Such a string can be created with the very opposite of `json.loads`, namely `json.dumps`:

```
df_ge.expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema(column='pg',json_schema=json.dumps(pgschema),row_condition="a=='1' and b=='2' and c=='3'",condition_parser='pandas')
```

Comment: thanks but using `dumps` gives me

`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict`

Comment: @AbtPst Then please update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).